# Forge Design Automation is failing to run one of the functions in my activity

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

It appears as though Forge Design Automation is unable to run a function in my activity that was working earlier in the day. No update to the app bundle or activity were changed. How do I resolve this issue?

```
    [09/02/2020 16:11:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Processing failed. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Autodesk.Inventor.Interop, Version=24.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d84147f8b4276564' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[09/02/2020 16:11:16] File name: 'Autodesk.Inventor.Interop, Version=24.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d84147f8b4276564'
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]    at UpdateUserParametersPlugin.SampleAutomation.GetQuote(String quoteFileName, String currentDir, Object doc, String quoteTemplate, String userName, String userEmail)
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]    at UpdateUserParametersPlugin.SampleAutomation.Run(Document placeholder) in C:\Users\kate.hilton\Desktop\da-update-user-params-master\da-update-user-params-master\UpdateUserParameters\UpdateUserParametersPlugin\SampleAutomation.cs:line 213
[09/02/2020 16:11:16] WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
[09/02/2020 16:11:16] To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
[09/02/2020 16:11:16] Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
[09/02/2020 16:11:16] To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Diagnostics failed: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]    at IvCoreConsole.Inv.InventorServerApp.PerformiLogicDiagnostics()
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: UpdateUserParametersPlugin
[09/02/2020 16:11:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateUserParametersPlugin: deactivating... 
[09/02/2020 16:11:17] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
```

Line 213:

```
var quoteFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathName), "Quote.txt");
                    LogTrace($"Getting the quote: filepath = {quoteFileName}");

                    (213) GetQuote(quoteFileName, currDir, aDoc, quoteTemplate, userName, userEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is strange that it worked previously. It seems like you are referencing Autodesk.Inventor.Interop DLL in a way which doesn't work on FDA. You can try to make a proper version of Autodesk.Inventor.Interop DLL part of your plugins bundle. If that will not work, can you post here how you reference it in your csproj file?

Comment: Michal, I don't think the problem is with referencing the Autodesk Interop. By line 213, the activity has already opened an assembly, changed some parameters, created the viewable files. It also closes and reopens the assembly because there were some problems with getting the BOM and that was the work around I found that solved the issue.

Comment: But there is something suspicious with the Interop based on 1st line. See InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Processing failed. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Autodesk.Inventor.Interop, Version=24.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d84147f8b4276564' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
I think this may be the cause of later problem. Can you post here your Plugins csproj file?